# Why is `gcd` the answer?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is [the original puzzle](http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASER_BEAM/)

Given an N by M grid. How many laser beams are necessary to cover the grid?

> Imagine a grid of size N × M, you can choose one node in the grid and
>   shot a laser beam, the laser can be shot only in diagonal direction as
>   shown in the picture above, if the laser reach the edge of the grid,
>   it'll bounce to other diagonal direction, and if the laser reach the
>   corner of the grid, it'll bounce back. The laser will form a loop
>   track.

The answer is `gcd(N-1, M-1)+1`.  And here are [some hints](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-approach-to-solve-SPOJ-problem-LASER_BEAM).

> 1. A grid with N dots in the horizontal direction to M in the vertical direction has length N - 1 in the horizontal direction and M - 1 in the vertical direction. Thinking in terms of length will be more useful than thinking in terms of number of lattice points.
> 2. Every laser track hits at least one point on the left edge. (This is true for every other edge too, but let’s focus on the left one.)
> 3. A point on the left edge is part of exactly one laser track. (Some points can be part of two different tracks, but for a point on the edge, those two tracks are always the same track, which reflects at the edge.)
> 4. Consider two points that are both on the left edge. Try colouring them based on which laser track they’re on. Do you notice a pattern? (It’s different depending on whether the point is part of a corner track or not.)

But I just don't get the hints.

Comment: I think the hints boil down to this: if you simply alternate through gcd(M-1,N-1)+1 colors on each edge, then one can color the entire grid with lasers in a manner which is consistent with that layout. This might be easiest to understand in the case where M-1 and N-1 are coprime, so that there are just two colors.

Comment: Just an FYI, this (but in the context of billiards) occupies the first couple of chapters of Jacobs' [*Mathematics: A Human Endeavor*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zO4ApMb3B8QC&pg=PA12&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false). You're reminding me I never did take the time to figure out what was going on, in those chapters...